# Lion Safari's enabled and disabled button contrast is so low it's hard to see the difference

Tags: macos, ui, accessibility

Is it me or is Lion's buttons' contrast way too low? The back button (enabled) and forward button (disabled) are almost the same shade of gray.

[image: safari screenshot]

Is there a way to increase the contrast between enabled and disabled? I tried `System Preferences - Universal Access - Display - Enhance contrast`, but it doesn't really enhance the contrast of the button.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, sadly, there is no UI control for changing such contrast. You'd have to play within the app's insides and it may cause problems down the way, and might have to be done every time the app is update. Therefore, much less trouble to live with it than change it. :-)

Comment: This was the **FIRST** thing about Lion that I noticed once I upgraded, and it's hard to get used to. I hate it. In my opinion the forward and back buttons are just about useless now, in that I can't figure out what state they are in by looking at them. I have to click on one to see whether it's functional or not. And I have better than 20/20 vision with my eyeglasses on, so it's not me.